# Checking to see if a C# WinForm is closed

Tags: c#, exit, formclosing

I am using the FormClosing event on a C# Windows Form to ask the user to confirm before exiting. I only wish to show this message if the user specifically closes the form using the red cross in the corner of the form window. When I close or hide a form manually I do not wish to show the confirm message (e.g. manually calling form.Close()).

Is it possible to check to see if the user has pressed the red cross?

Thanks.

Comment: Well I have some buttons to open a new form which closes the previous form behind it (using form.Close()). This will therefore bring up the message which asks the user to confirm. Sorry I did not make this clear.

Comment: @Yuck: Imagine that this is a technical question, and not one about your opinions on design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the [FormClosingEventArgs.CloseReason](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs.closereason.aspx) property.

Answer (score 2):

If you programatically call `this.Close()` or have the user clicking the X, you get the `CloseReason.UserClosing` for both so thats not a valid check.

See the below code for a "hacky" solution which basically invokes this.Close if OnClosing is passed a `null` parameter.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OnClosing(null);
}
protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (e == null)
    {
        // Raise your Message or Cancel
        this.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        base.OnClosing(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: is using this.Dispose() a bad way to close a form that is open? I will not require the information which is in the form again but I may actually use the form again later in the application with different information (i.e. just using the layout again).

Comment: Usually, this.Dispose() calls .Close() internally - so it should be fine.

Comment: Using this.Dispose() was not classed under "UserClosing". Thanks for you help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `CloseReason` property of the event args passed to the `FormClosing` event.

Answer (score 0):

use `FormClosing` event handler and put this simple code:

```
        if (MessageBox.Show(this, "Do you want to close the Application?", "Exit App", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.No)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        else
        {
            //close app code
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, there isn't an easy way to detect this kind of behaviour.  While there is a "FormClosingEventArgs.CloseReason" property that you can check on the FormClosing event, it won't really get specific about the reason it closes.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.closereason.aspx), the description of the 'UserClosing' enum value is:

> The user is closing the form through the user interface (UI), for
>   example by clicking the Close button on the form window, selecting
>   Close from the window's control menu, or pressing ALT+F4.

So as you can see there are a lot of reasons listed, but not one specifically.

I think that the best you are going to do is remove the window border (including the buttons) and place your own close button upon it, and catch its click event to get the behaviour that you want.  I've seen it done before, and it does work, though it may not look as 'nice' as the normal window buttons.